# spring SFTP outbound gateway transfer file to other location

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring SFTP outbound gateway to download file on a server on a location. I now have to move / copy the file to another location on the server to archive it. Can I use same channel for that ? Do need to configure separate channel for that or can we use the same channel as we are using for download ?  The SFTP server is same

Thanks,

Aiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need separate gateways - each gateway is configured to perform a single operation type (get, put etc) and cannot be used for both.

```
...>getGateway->...do some work on file if needed...->putGateway
```